# How to send key and mouse events to a Java applet?

Tags: java, c++, winapi, visual-c++, applet

I'm trying to control some Java game from FireFox window. How can I send key and mouse events to that Java applet?

I'm using Windows XP if that matters.

**Edit:** I'm not trying to do this with Java even though i have the tag here. A c++ solution would be optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try using [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html), but this might not work in FireFox. You can also use methods like abstractbutton.doClick()

If Robot doesn't work, key events you can synthesize by just setting text on a component, and mouse events you can use doClick() and requestFocus()

If none of that works, you might be able to accomplish your goals working with javascript and an html page.

Comment: Care to elaborate on "Robot" ? (a link would be good). Hard to google it as it is very common word.

Comment: If you google "Java Robot" this is the #1 link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html anyway you have it now

Comment: Cool, you should edit your message though, (I tried to add the link there but it needs review). I'm not sure how this Robot is going to help because I'm trying to control another Java applet, which isnt my code.. (not to mention i havent made a single Java applet yet, so i would prefer c++ solution for this).

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that will work for keystrokes:

The recommended methods for both these actions are using [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
This website is perfect for beginning to [understand sendinput](http://alala666888.wordpress.com/2010/09/17/simulate-mouse-event-using-sendinput-and-setcursorpos/)

To find windows targets use [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460760.aspx)

but I do have other examples below:

Example here is for Notepad using [postmessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
#include "TCHAR.h"
#include "Windows.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HWND hwndWindowTarget;
    HWND hwndWindowNotepad = FindWindow(NULL, L"Untitled - Notepad");
    if (hwndWindowNotepad)
    {
        // Find the target Edit window within Notepad.
        hwndWindowTarget = FindWindowEx(hwndWindowNotepad, NULL, L"Edit", NULL);
        if (hwndWindowTarget) {
            PostMessage(hwndWindowTarget, WM_CHAR, 'G', 0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You may also like to look at [windows hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which can send mouse input
Or [User32 mouse_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
[DllImport("User32.Dll")]
private static extern void mouse_event(UInt32 dwFlags, int dx, int dy, UInt32 dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y); 

public enum MouseEventFlags
{
    LEFTDOWN = 0x00000002,
    LEFTUP = 0x00000004,
    MIDDLEDOWN = 0x00000020,
    MIDDLEUP = 0x00000040,
    MOVE = 0x00000001,
    ABSOLUTE = 0x00008000,
    RIGHTDOWN = 0x00000008,
    RIGHTUP = 0x00000010
}

public static void SendLeftClick(int X, int Y)
{
    mouse_event((uint)MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    mouse_event((uint)MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Will that `FindWindowEx` work for Java Applet? The applet is inside FireFox window, i know i can find firefox window with `FindWindowEx` but how about the applet which is inside that HTML page? How can i "find" that?

Comment: You should be able to find it if you know it's name =d, it might be a bit difficult though, in the example code it finds the "edit" handle within notepad so it should be doable, but I have absolutely no idea how Firefox handles its windows.`https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Finding_Window_Handles` may help, or use `Spy++`

Comment: Spy++ indeed finds the handle. How could I make that handle finder myself that Spy++ uses? (that which i can move with my mouse and it shows each window borders it hits).

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't have the first idea, I've only ever sent input to windows I've found with spy++, I suppose you can try http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/70823-enumchildwindows/